# Подключиться к серверу особым способом

Tags: java, android

Я умею делать запросы на сервер `GET/POST`. А вот, если мне надо постоянно получать данные, то как быть? Неужели, такие же запросы, но в бесконечном цикле? Как это делать?

Comment: Читай сокетные соединения. TCP/UDP

Comment: Спасибо теперь хоть знаю куда копать

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под "Сервер". Если web-сервер - то боюсь только так, правда соединение после GET можно попробовать не закрывать, выставив заголовок Keep-Alive, но запросы все равно слать придется. А вот если "Сервер" - это нечто большее, чем понимающее только протокол HTTP - то да, UDP/TCP или может ваш сервер Websocket протокол поддерживает

Comment: Вам наверное подойдет long polling - соединение открывается, но не закрывается долгое время и через него можно передавать данные. Правда надо будет по другому обрабатывать соединение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В наше время если говорят "сервер", то подразумевают "веб-сервер". Для веб-серверов для непрерывного получения данных реализован протокол [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Писал клиента на Андроиде с использованием [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), работает.